# GCKMediaInformation initWithContentID is deprecated warning

Tags: ios, chromecast

While building [GCKMediaInformation](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/ios/interface_g_c_k_media_information) I get this warning:

> 'initWithContentID:streamType:contentType:metadata:streamDuration:mediaTracks:textTrackStyle:customData:'
>   is deprecated: Use GCKMediaInformationBuilder to initialize
>   GCKMediaInformation objects.

here is my method:

```
GCKMediaInformation* mediaInfo = [[GCKMediaInformation alloc]
    initWithContentID:[self.chromecastUrl absoluteString] // WARNING ON THIS LINE
           streamType:self.videoPlayer.isLive ? GCKMediaStreamTypeLive
                                              : GCKMediaStreamTypeBuffered
          contentType:@"application/dash+xml"
             metadata:metadata
       streamDuration:duration
          mediaTracks:nil
       textTrackStyle:nil
           customData:customData];
```

how to pass that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I pass that warning by building the media information with [GCKMediaInformationBuilder](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/ios/interface_g_c_k_media_information_builder):

```
GCKMediaInformationBuilder *builder =
[[GCKMediaInformationBuilder alloc] initWithContentURL:self.chromecastUrl];
builder.contentType = @"application/dash+xml";
builder.streamType = self.videoPlayer.isLive ? GCKMediaStreamTypeLive : GCKMediaStreamTypeBuffered;
builder.metadata = metadata;
builder.streamDuration = duration;
builder.customData = customData;
// set all other desired properties...

// then build the GCKMediaInformation with build method
GCKMediaInformation *mediaInfo = [builder build];
```

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is looking for the Swift version, here it is.

```
let builder = GCKMediaInformationBuilder()

builder.contentType = "application/dash+xml"
builder.streamType = self.videoPlayer.isLive ? .live : .buffered
builder.metadata = metadata
builder.streamDuration = duration
builder.customData = customData
// set all other desired properties...

// then build the GCKMediaInformation with build method
let mediaInfo = builder.build()
```